# restore sharepoint config cache

Tags: sharepoint, configuration

I've cone and accidentally deleted the entire config cache at `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\<GUID>` (by following the instructions as indicated here: http://www.marc-antho-etc.net/blog/post/2009/04/03/A-Clockwork-Orange-Some-SharePoint-Timer-Job-Issues-without-Beethovene280a6.aspx).  How do I go about restoring?  The only thing I've been able to find about this so far is that I shouldn't have deleted the `<GUID>` directory :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this: http://tomblog.insomniacminds.com/2008/07/30/sharepoint-internals-clearing-configuration-cache-caveat/

Apparently the GUID is just the config db ID.  I kinda figured, but it helps to know that someone else came to the same conclusion.

Also, I just discovered that you can cause the cache to be rebuilt by executing the `stsadm -o setconfigdb` command.

**update**: I just discovered that running the above stsadm command actually wipes out the existing config db and creates a new one, so it will solve the problem, but it's the 'nuclear option'.

Comment: Use -connect attribute to connect to existing config database. Or just use SharePoint Configuration Wizard which will do the same.

Comment: I tried the sharepoint configuration wizard to no effect, which is why I ended up trying to do it using stsadm.  Thanks for the tip, though.